# Trying to add sockets to rings but don't succeed

Tags: diablo-iii

It's as if the other alternatives  that the mystic gives me are basically the same.

Is it possible to add sockets to rings or amulet through easier ways?

I have done this like 10-20 times per ring and wasted so many imperial ruby gems. I simply don't get sockets.

Am I missing something? Should I keep trying.

Comment: Sometimes you get lucky, sometimes you don't you'll have to keep trying

Comment: I read this first thinking the OP was having issue getting the gem into a socket, after rereading it a few times I understod he was trying to reroll stats on his gear to get a socket into a ring. With regards to that try getting max weapon damage for a specific element damage type

Comment: I enchant the wrong stats

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check whether a socket is a valid enchantment property by clicking the question mark next to the property you are enchanting, which will show a list of all possible properties and their potential rolls.  As far as I know, Blizzard has not released a formula explaining how each possible roll is weighted - it may be that each unique property has an equal chance of rolling, and if chosen it is then rolled for a number, or it may be that some properties are weighted higher than others.  The only thing that we know for sure is that if a property is on the list of possible properties, it has a nonzero chance of being selected when the item is enchanted.

Comment: The formula was datamined, some affixes have larger weights. For example, main stat and vitality are x4 more probable, and +%elemental damage (for Amulets) is TEN times more probable. See [this answer] and link in it for data on Rings. Data is as old as 2.0.6, but nothing better seems to be available.

Answer (score 8):

The mystic is the only way to add a socket to a ring or amulet.  Sometimes you get bad luck and take a lot of rolls, that's why its the RNG.

However, keep in mind that a socket occupies a PRIMARY slot.  If you are trying to roll one on the secondary effects it will not be possible.

Comment: It's also worth noting that if you've modified a property and for whatever reason it's not possible to even roll a socket on it, you may have to find a new ring.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf that is true, I'll update my post

Answer (score 0):

If you have made a mistake of enchanting the wrong slot, you can reforge the item. It's pretty expensive. 50 forgotten souls plus 5 of each bounties reward. Not sure what it's called. But I'd rather do that than wait for another compass rose.